# How to parse a specific column and keep only a part with awk

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing, awk

I have a file like this `A.txt` (field separator = `,`) :

```
Kit Batch Export
Software Version = NO_v1
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name = MY20195334_MOL_2014_20201006Run180017
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = Cji
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Nov
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis,EC,CH
,MY20195334_MOL_2014_20201006Run180017,2061571293,A01,Unkn-01,VALID,,,
,MY20195334_MOL_2014_20201006Run180017,2061584371,A02,Unkn-09,VALID,,,

*See Kit IFU for reporting activities.
CE-IVD
For In Vitro Diagnostic Use.
```

And I want to parse the column 2 by keeping only what comes after the first `_` and before the third `_` , like that :

```
Kit Batch Export
Software Version = NO_v1
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name = MY20195334_MOL_2014_20201006Run180017
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = Cji
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Nov
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis,EC,CH
,MOL_2014,2061571293,A01,Unkn-01,VALID,,,
,MOL_2014,2061584371,A02,Unkn-09,VALID,,,

*See Kit IFU for reporting activities.
CE-IVD
For In Vitro Diagnostic Use.
```

In order to do that, I try something like that :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==4{split($1,a,"_")} NR>13{$2=a[2]"_"a[3]} 1' A.txt > B.txt
```

It works but the print keep going at the end of the file like that :

```
Kit Batch Export
Software Version = NO_v1
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name = MY20195334_MOL_2014_20201006Run180017
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = Cji
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Nov
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis,EC,CH
,MOL_2014,2061571293,A01,Unkn-01,VALID,,,
,MOL_2014,2061584371,A02,Unkn-09,VALID,,,
,MOL_2014
*See Kit IFU for reporting activities.,MOL_2014
CE-IVD,MOL_2014
For In Vitro Diagnostic Use.,MOL_2014
```

Can someone have an idea how to fix that ? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without knowing more about the rules of the file format - but you could limit the replacement to records that have a non-empty second field i.e. change `NR>13` to `NR>13 && $2!=""` or perhaps to those that have more than one field `NR>13 && NF>1`

Comment: Thanks , add `$2!=` is a good idea and works well !